# TXT file in jsp not getting displayed

Tags: java, jsp

Hey I have written a JSP which takes a .txt file from File system and needs to display it line by line.But for some reason its not getting displayed.Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DrAssist Reporting Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Welcome to the DrAssist Reporting Tool</p>
    <p>Suite Report Information</p>
    <h1>Suite : ${suite}</h1>
    <h1>NoOfTests:${noOfTests}</h1> 
    <h1>Test Name:${TestName}</h1>  
    <h1>FitnesseRestURL:${FitnesseRestURL}</h1> 
    <h1>Rights:${rights}</h1>   
    <h1>Wrongs:${wrongs}</h1>   
    <h1>Ignores:${ignores}</h1> 
    <h1>Exceptions:${exceptions}</h1>   
    <h1>TimeinMilliseconds:${timeOfExecution}</h1>  
    <%@ include file="Test1.html" %>
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.net.Authenticator,java.net.PasswordAuthentication,java.io.BufferedReader,java.net.*,java.io.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\DrAssistQA\\reports\\120703-100125\\log-120703-100125.txt"));
     String line = "";
     while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
}
  out.flush();
  input.close();
%>


<%=line%>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ewewewew. So much cleaner to just read the file into a string in a servlet or utility class and display that string with JSP EL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `out.println` instead of `System.out.println`. `out` is a variable automatically created in JSP for browser output stream manipilation. Also don't forget the HTML line breaks.

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
     out.println(line + "<BR>");
}
```

Comment: I did that but its not working.To be clear I am already displaying a .html file ahead of .txt file.Is that a problem.I dont think so but still asking and does the .txt need to be in Web-INF/pages directory.

Comment: Its no problem to display the html file beforehand.

Comment: then what could be the problem.

Comment: Did you undeploy your old war file properly? Its possible that the old one is still deployed.

Comment: Hey Thanks @Reimeus Actually Its working But I am not getting the output as line by line.Its getting showed as a Table.I tried <p><%=line%></p> but didnt work.Any suggestions.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's going to your system out not the browser window. Try `response.write()` instead.